# Java criteria builder query not null or empty

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I'm trying to check if a column in the db is not an empty string or not null but I can't figure out how to do it with criteria builder queries in order to get actual objects back.  This sql works:

```
sampleName is not null and sampleName != ''
```

But when I try to do it with criteria builder like this:

// this is in a private method filterBySampleNotEmpty

```
cb.notEqual(root.get("sampleName"), "");
```

called by this in another method

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Sample> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Sample.class);
Root model = query.from(Sample.class);
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
predicates.add(filterBySampleNotEmpty(model, criteriaBuilder));
query.select(model).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
```

It returns the whole list still.

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your code? How have you built/configured cb and root?

Comment: @EddieCurtis My bad, I added more.

Comment: In the 'where' clause, can you try `predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]` and see if that works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please make a try with the following

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Sample> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Sample.class);
MetaModel m = em.getMetaModel();
EntityType<Sample> entity = m.entity(Sample.class);
Root model = query.from(Sample.class);
query.where(criteriaBuilder.notEqual(model.get(entity.name), “”)).and(criteriaBuilder.notEqual(model.get(entity.name), null));
```

Comment: the notEqual cannot be called on the query.

Comment: Yeah, made a mistake @Crystal.. notEquals must be on `CriteriaBuilder` have edited my answer please check the same

Comment: Please refer the following java doc https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjixa/index.html - to know more..

Answer (score 22):

Try to use this code:

```
criteriaBuilder.isNotNull(model.get(entity.name))
```

Comment: Try to give a bit more context in your answer. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is correct. notEqual (entity, null) may throw NPE.

Comment: What if the column has just a blank space as the string value?

Comment: Then it won't be considered `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

The criteria builder "notEqual" criteria testing that two expressions are not equal. I can not see the criteria to filter null value unless I missed something.

Comment: yes i was trying for the empty string first but could not get that to work.

Answer (score 0):

In the 'where' clause, try `predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]` and see if that works. When you are converting the `List` to `Array`, you are specifying the size as 0 since you are passing an empty array.

Comment: No, the array will be resized automatically.